# SEM_MATCH call returns ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, rdf, oracle-spatial

When trying to run examples from  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25609/sem_apis_ref.htm everything is ok except the most important call of SPARQL query. Here's the shortened version of the example "family" script:

```
CREATE TABLE family_rdf_data (id NUMBER, triple SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S);
EXECUTE SEM_APIS.create_sem_model('family', 'family_rdf_data', 'triple');

INSERT INTO family_rdf_data VALUES (15, 
SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S('family', 
'<http://www.example.org/family/Tom>', 
'<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>',
'<http://www.example.org/family/Male>'));
COMMIT;

-- Select all males from the family model, without inferencing.
SELECT m
  FROM TABLE(SEM_MATCH(
    '{?m rdf:type :Male}',
    SEM_Models('family'),
    null,
    SEM_ALIASES(SEM_ALIAS('','http://www.example.org/family/')),
    null));
```

SQLPLUS output:

```
Table created.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


1 row created.


Commit complete.

SELECT m
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

All similar calls from these examples fail with the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get when you run an *exact* example statement, e.g. `SELECT x, SEM_APIS.COMPOSE_RDF_TERM(h, h$RDFVTYP, h$RDFLTYP, h$RDFLANG)
       h_rdf_term, h
  FROM TABLE(SEM_MATCH(
    '{?x :height ?h}',
    SEM_Models('family'),
    null, 
    SEM_ALIASES(SEM_ALIAS('','http://www.example.org/family/')),
    null))
ORDER BY x;` ?

Comment: I've got exactly the same error "invalid datatype"

Comment: I've run the very same example in the Oracle demo virtual machine (available on Oracle site) and it works perfectly. I'm not a DBA so I don't even have a clue in which direction I should look.

Comment: This might be version-related. Could you please add the output of `select * from product_component_version` for both databases (your own and the Oracle Demo VM) to your question?

Comment: The issue has been resolved with reinstallation of Oracle database and proper deployment of Spatial Option. Thanks a lot, @FrankSchmitt!

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you add this as an answer and accept it. This will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions and might be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved with reinstallation of Oracle database from scratch including Spatial Option from the start.